# OSX Fullscreen API and Menu Bar

Tags: macos, delegates, fullscreen

When using the OSX FullScreen API, is there a way to detect whether the Menu Bar (or the Dock, for that matter) are currently being displayed over top of your application?

For example, a delegate which notifies the application when the Menu Bar animates in, and then sends another notification when the Menu Bar animates out?

Answer (score 0):

NSMenu.menuBarVisible()

there's also NSMenuBarDelegate protocol which has menuWillOpen() and menuWillClose(). but so far I haven't gotten any luck with this one